# UISelect with multiple select to show count instead of items selected

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Hi I want to implement a ui-select for multiple items in such a way that it should show counts of the items selected rather than items tags itself.
i.e if three items A,B and C are selected then showing A,B,C in ui-select-match or text area it should show 3 items with cross.

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.removeSelectIsFalse" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" close-on-select="false" style="width: 800px;" title="Choose a person" remove-selected="false">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="person in ctrl.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
          <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          <small>
            email: {{person.email}}
            age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
          </small>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```